# Why some variables aren't listed on strongarm feature component list?

Tags: 7, features, configuration, strongarm

I want to export 2 variables from domain navigation module:

- domain_nav_block
- domain_nav_theme

I am sure that this vars exists in variables table, but in strongarm tab there are missing...

Comment: All I can say is that I can't think of a reason those variables wouldn't be available to StrongArm. There doesn't seem to be any logic in the `strongarm_vars_load()` function that would exclude certain variables. Double check that they are, in fact, set in the `variable` table. Note that those two variables are **only** set when you save the "Domain list navigator" block (they aren't set when you enable the "Domain Navigation" module).

Comment: @AdamBalsam yes, I have this block options saved.

Comment: For what it's worth, I installed the Domain Access and Domain Navigation modules in a sandbox - then installed strongarm and features (after saving the "Domain list navigator" block) - and I can confirm that the `domain_nav_block` and `domain_nav_theme` variables are available to strongarm. So it looks like there is something unique to your installation. Perhaps those vars are being set by another Feature Module? Or perhaps Bulk Export?

Comment: @AdamBalsam thans a lot. I've checked that too. No features with these vars. Strange...